# How to change the color about contextMenuBuilder

Tags: flutter

I'm using contextMenuBuilder to enable the use of SelectableText.
When debugging on the iOS platform, it appears like this.
[image: This is a screenshot]
Could somebody please tell me how to handle dark mode?"

I referred to the documentation, but there is no mention of it.

Answer (score 0):

The background color of the

*contextMenuBuilder*

is Handled by

```
final Widget outputChild = _CupertinoTextSelectionToolbarShape(
      anchor: anchor,
      isAbove: isAbove,
      child: ColoredBox(
        color: _kToolbarBackgroundColor.resolveFrom(context),
        child: child,
      ),
    );
```

for ios and similarly for Android stating.

> For example, if the given [BuildContext] indicates the widgets in the
> subtree should be displayed in dark mode (the surrounding
> [CupertinoTheme]'s [CupertinoThemeData.brightness] or [MediaQuery]'s
> [MediaQueryData.platformBrightness] is [Brightness.dark]), with a high
> accessibility contrast (the surrounding [MediaQuery]'s
> [MediaQueryData.highContrast] is true), and an elevated interface
> elevation (the surrounding [CupertinoUserInterfaceLevel]'s data is
> [CupertinoUserInterfaceLevelData.elevated]), the resolved
> [CupertinoDynamicColor] will be the same as this
> [CupertinoDynamicColor], except its effective color will be the
> darkHighContrastElevatedColor variant from the original
> [CupertinoDynamicColor].

Try Wrapping the Parent Tree with Theme Widget or checking the theme configuration that you already have.

```
brightness: Brightness.dark
```

Property is being followed while on dark theme.

Comment: _CupertinoTextSelectionToolbarShape isn't defined.
What should I do?